# Custom AnnotationAspect doesnt get called

Tags: java, unit-testing, aspectj, spring-aop, mdc

I am trying to implement a Custommade annotation that contains a value as a parameter and when the annotation is used, this value should be processed with a MDC.put.

So when I use a method with the annotation @Usecase("TestUsecase"), MDC.get("usecase") should actually output "TestUsecase", but currently I only get null. When debugging I noticed that the method in my UsecaseAspect is never called.

I have already tried several things:

- in my TestApplication I have already set @EnableAspectJAutoProxy.
- In my POM I have set both the dependency for aspectjweaver and spring-boot-starter-aop

Here some code:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Usecase {
    String value();
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class UsecaseAspect {

    @After("@annotation(usecase)")
    public void setLoggingContext(@NotNull Usecase usecase) {
        MDC.put("usecase", usecase.value());

    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles({"test", "tests"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
class UsecaseTest {

    @Usecase("TestUsecase")
    public void testUsecaseMethod() {
    }

    @Test
    void testUsecaseAnnotation() {
        testUsecaseMethod();
        assertEquals("TestUsecase", MDC.get("usecase"));
    }
}
```